# Dynamically add a span tag to the first word of a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i'm working on a react project where i'm passing titles contained in states to a children element (see bottom). 
How can i dynamically add  to the first word (and only the first word cause my titles can contain 2 or 3 words) inside the this.state.title inside the child element?

```
//Parent

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './child';

class Parent extends Component {

    state = {
        title:'Admin Picture'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Child title={this.state.title}>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default Parent;


//Child

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Child extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <span className="title">{this.props.title}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
export default Child;
```

Comment: Where you have the curly braces - `{this.state.title}` - you can put any Javascript expression. If you are not familiar with splitting strings look at this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the Child component.

```
//Child

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        const splitTitle = this.props.title.split(' ');
        const firstWord = splitTitle.shift();
        const remainingTitle = splitTitle.join(' ');

        return (
            <div>
                <span className="title">{firstWord}</span>
                {remainingTitle}
            </div>
        );
    }
};
export default Child;
```

Alternatively, you could also pass `firstWord` and `remainingTitle` to Child component as a prop. You would probably want to name them something different.

Comment: You may also want to separate the words with a space.  You can add something like this `{' '}` between the `<span>` and `{remaining title}`